# Why isn't change button content working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code:

```
private void ModifyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ModifyButton.Content = "Another button name";
}
```

But it doesn't work. I mean, the modify button content doesn't change but the program doesn't fail or throw any exception.

I'm trying to modify the button name in order to change it's behavior (kinda Edit/Save) within the same button. Is this not possible using C#/WPF?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

XAML:

```
<Button Name="ModifyButton" Content="Modificar" Margin="5,10,0,0" Height="23" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="ModifyButton_Click"></Button>
```

WEIRD BEHAVIOR: If I put a MessageBox.Show call after the change of the button content, then, while the message box is displayed the button dislay the new (changed) name, but after the message box is closed, then it shows it's original text.

Comment: It might help if you add the XAML part of your code, too.

Comment: It's definitely possible. Try to see if you can replicate this using a small test project. Place a breakpoint in the body of your event handler and see if your code gets there.

Comment: @Sensei76 I just put the XAML. KshitijMehta the code is "executing", I mean, the debugger call the event.

Comment: What you have posted works fine for me. Is there anything additional you're not showing, such as background/dispatcher calls, custom templates, etc?

Comment: Nope, nothing weird @Rachel One interesting thing is that if I don't change the button's content but it visibily to hide then it doesn't appear (so that works).

Comment: Can you try `((Button)sender).Content = "Anther Button Name";`?

Comment: Your code works for me as pasted above.  Is the datacontext of your window set?

Comment: @mydogisbox That doesn't work neither.

Comment: @GuyStarbuck I don't have any datacontext this isn't MVVM is a simple event :S

Comment: I have tried the code that you showed above and it works. Try double clicking on the button in the window itself which should take to the .cs file. Then compile and run it.

Comment: @AlexMendez the button is well coded with it's code behind executing. See my edit.

Comment: Is there any animation on the button Content property, even finished? Animated values take precedence over locally set values.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain Nop. Plain button. I think it has something to do with the threading model. Given the weird behavior with the message box.

Comment: Yor problem is inded caused by ShowDialog(). Please see my comment below.

Comment: Changing the content of a button is trivial, and as you can see people cannot reproduce this problem. You are not giving us the full picture, **something** in your code changes the value back and we cannot divine what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the XAML of your UI is not bound to the value of your button. Did you check the DataBinding?

**[EDIT]**

Your ***magic*** information here is that you use `ShowDialog()`. As you already guessed, this influences your UI thread and therefore the display behavior. `ShowDialog()` displays the Form   as a **modal** dialog and blocks your UI thread and therefore blocks the refresh of it. This may cause all sorts of weird behavior.

Comment: It is bound. I run the debugger and executes but UI doesn't change.

Comment: I just tried your example in a test project. Works fine for me. BTW, sorry, there is no databinding at all. I just read in the other comments that you do not use MVVM here? If you're working with WPF I strongly suggest you use MVVM to make use of WPF's capabilities.

Comment: thanks, do you know how can I modify this behavior Sensei76 or it just not possible?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. Would it be possible to just use 'Show()' instead?

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul Sorry, without knowing your code it is too hard to say. But like I said, if you want to use the WPF you **really** should use the MVVM pattern. That would make your life much, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have and it works:

Window 1

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="ModifyButton" Content="Open Dialog" Margin="80,104,78,0" Height="23" Click="ModifyButton_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ModifyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 win2 = new Window2();
        win2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Window 2

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="ModifyButton" Content="Modificar" Margin="80,104,78,0" Height="23" Click="ModifyButton_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ModifyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ModifyButton.Content = "Another button name";
    }
}
```

Comment: I also have the same (with other controls and so on). One particular thing is that I'm Showing this windows as a ShowDialog() from another one.

Comment: Still works for me if I use a dialog. See changes above. Maybe is time for the old trusty step. If all else fails, reboot your machine.